# Borrar valores duplicados en un Map/HashMap y obtener el valor mas frecuente

Tags: java, manejo-de-memoria, hashmap

He tratado de borrar llaves y valores de un `map` sin embargo aun no lo he logrado, mientras tanto he creado otro `map`.

1. Se requiere encontrar las palabras con mas apariciones en una oración. (No se que palabras pueda haber en la oración ni tengo una lista con que comparar).
2. Obtener la palabra que aparece mas veces sin importar mayúsculas, minúsculas o acentos.
3. Encontrar la segunda y tercer palabra con mas apariciones en la oración.
4. Imprimir el top 3 de dichas palabras con su valor.
5. **Ser lo mas eficiente posible en la codificacion.**

El punto 5 es el mas importante, a continuación les muestro lo que tengo.

```
public class StringTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String stringTest = "En esta cadena tenemos mas cadenas que la cadena principal la primera vez que intente esta solucion no pude mas que intentar una y otra vez vez vez vez";
        new StringTest(stringTest);

    }

    public StringTest(String string) {

        String [] splitString = string.split(" ");
        Map<String, Integer> mapString = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        mapString.put(splitString[0], 1);

        for (int i=1; i <= splitString.length-1; i++){
            if (mapString.containsKey(splitString[i])){
                mapString.put(splitString[i], mapString.get(splitString[i])+1);
            } else{
                mapString.put(splitString[i], 1);
            }
        }

        Map<String, Integer> newMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : mapString.entrySet()){
            if (entry.getValue()!=1){
                newMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }

        System.out.println(newMap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plantearé una solución usando `Streams` para obtener las palabras y la cantidad de veces que se repiten. Todo esto se guardará en un `Map` en primera instancia

```
String stringTest = "En esta cadena tenemos mas cadenas que la cadena "
           + "principal la primera vez que intente esta solución no pude mas que "
           + "intentar una y otra vez vez vez vez vez";
String[] valores = stringTest.split(" "); /* Obtenemos las Palabras */
```

Luego de obtener las palabras del `String` se hace uso de `Streams` , Convertimos a `lista` el `array` para luego mediante el método [collect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) para realizar una reducción del `array` inicial , lo reducirá básicamente a una [Agrupación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) de clave , valor que serán asignados al `Map` , donde la clave será la palabra y el valor el total de repeticiones , para esto se emplea el método [counting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting--) de la clase [Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html)

```
Map<String, Long> repeticiones = Arrays.asList(valores).stream().
                            collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w, Collectors.counting()));
```

Esto nos devolverá los valores desordenados pero como se desea obtener los valores con mayor cantidad de repeticiones, empleamos `Stream` nuevamente , donde el método principal es [reverseOrder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder--) que devolverá los valores de mayor a menor.

```
Stream<Map.Entry<String, Long>> ordenados = repeticiones.entrySet().stream()
.sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()));
```

Para luego obtener los tres primeros valores aplicando un `limit`

```
ordenados .limit(3).forEach(i -> System.out.println("Palabra " + i.getKey() 
                                + " , Se repite " + i.getValue()+ " veces"));
```

Sí desea ver todas las palabras y el total de repeticiones tendría que iterar el primer `map`

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : repeticiones.entrySet())
    System.out.println("Palabra : " + entry.getKey()+
                        " , Se Repite : " + entry.getValue()+ " Veces");
```

Comment: Tu solucion me parece sumamente elegante, sin embargo que puedes decirme acerca del procesamiento y manejo de memoria? Digamos que este proceso sera para revisar 15 millones de palabras / oraciones.

Comment: Por cierto, me parece excelente tu explicacion.

Comment: Sería un tema extenso hablar de memoria y rendimiento, pero para este problema en particular preferí sugerir una alternativa _quizá hayan más eficaces_  además el código simple es de mi preferencia.

Comment: No olvidar si mi respuesta resolvió sus dudas o problemas marcarla como aceptada. Gracias y saludos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar **TreeSet** para hacerlo más eficiente, TreeSet  no permite elementos duplicados, mantiene la lista ordenada y usarías como valor para ordenarlo la cantidad de repeticiones de dicha palabra.